# Exposing Additional Form Fields via Checked Radio Buttons in html and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have two radio button one for credit card and one for debit card. If i press any one of my radio button, I should get a form which comes under credit and for debit.

## Current Code

```
<div class="forcredit">
  <label>Card no:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cardno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
  <label>CVV no:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cvvno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
  <label>Expiration MM/YYYY</label>
  <input type="month" name="expire" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
</div>
```

but the problem is, I'm not able to expose additional form when I press radio button.

my whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="#">
  
  <h4>Payment type:</h4>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="credit" id="credit" required>
      <label>Credit card</label>
    
      <div class="forcredit">
      <label>Card no:</label>
      <input type="text" name="cardno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span><br>
      <label>CVV no:</label>
      <input type="text" name="cvvno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span><br>
      <label>Expiration MM/YYYY</label>
      <input type="month" name="expire" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="debit" id="debit">
      <label>Debit card</label>
    
      <div class="fordebit">
      <label>Card no:</label>
      <input type="text" name="cardno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span><br>
      <label>CVV no:</label>
      <input type="text" name="cvvno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span><br>
      <label>Expiration MM/YYYY</label>
      <input type="month" name="expire" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay">
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone reform the CSS file so that when ever I press the radio button a similar type of form should be displayed?

Comment: Where is your CSS? Please update your question to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to add :checked status in your css to display next sibling

```
  input[type=radio] + .fordebit,
  input[type=radio] + .forcredit{
    display:none;
  }
  input[type=radio]:checked + .fordebit{
     display:block;
  }
  input[type=radio]:checked + .forcredit{
     display:block;
  }
```

UPDATE

Ok here is an update. there were some issues with your html too. if you want to use radio buttons for multiple choice items, they should have same name. See the full working code below

```css
input[type=radio] + .details{
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .fordebit {
  display: block;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .forcredit {
  display: block;
}
input[type=radio] {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">

  <h4>Payment type:</h4>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Credit card</label>
      <input type="radio" name="payment_type" id="credit" required>

      <div class="forcredit details">
        <label>Card no:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cardno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
        <br>
        <label>CVV no:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cvvno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
        <br>
        <label>Expiration MM/YYYY</label>
        <input type="month" name="expire" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Debit card</label>
      <input type="radio" name="payment_type" id="debit">

      <div class="fordebit details">
        <label>Card no:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cardno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
        <br>
        <label>CVV no:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cvvno" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
        <br>
        <label>Expiration MM/YYYY</label>
        <input type="month" name="expire" required=""><span style="color: red;">*</span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay">
  </div>
```

Comment: buti am using sublime text :checked is not working in that @guyfawkes

Comment: very confused. you are using Sublime Text to write code, Sublime text is not a browser

Answer (score -2):

CSS can't do this.  Javascript is required for event capturing.  Using a library like jquery, you'll need to attach a click event handler to the card selector radio button.  Double check your radio button names, then you'll need something like:

```
$('.card').click(function() {
  $('.forcredit').show();
});
```

Comment: you can enable siblings by :checked css selector.

Comment: CSS most certainly *can* do this. Also, why incur the overhead of JQuery when plain ol' normal, everyday JavaScript can do the job?